# Event not getting triggered on Key Press

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<multiselect v-model="value" :options="websites" label="url" track-by="url" :allow-empty="false" class="header-select mr-3" v-on:keyup.enter="submit"></multiselect>
```

Requirement - I have searchable dropdown, initially I will not have any dropdown items, But once a user enters a letter I wish to call an api that will give me a list of dropdown items starting with that letter ( eg Typing A should return apple, ant ... etc )

In short - I need an input field with dropdown. ( similar to google-search )

Key press event is not working in the multiselect, There are events for @change etc that works on selecting the dropdown item of that multiselect, But I wanted the keypress to work and trigger an event. - https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-events

I used an npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-multiselect, https://vue-multiselect.js.org/ ( We can't achieve this with normal input field right ? Keypress would work there , but how to combine it with a dropdown ? )

Can anyone help me to solve this problem , If the problem is with the package that it cannot trigger a key up event, can anyone suggest another package for this purpose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i've gone over the codebase of that component and there is no @keydown event as the parent is not an input. It's wrapped in a div.

There is an event that is triggered when the search term is updated which can be seen [here](https://github.com/shentao/vue-multiselect/blob/ac46a71a38d9d2b01df560091992d38d712e857c/src/multiselectMixin.js#L397)

The event you want to listen for is `@search-change`

e.g.

```
    <multiselect
    v-model="value"
    :options="websites"
    label="url"
    track-by="url"
    :allow-empty="false"
    class="header-select mr-3"
    @search-update="myFunctionThatWillTriggerSomething"
    v-on:keyup.enter="submit"/>
```

But be aware, Triggering your api call when the `search-update` event is called will spam your api. You will want to look at debouncing it.